# How to identify if a DataGrid Cell is being edited?

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf-controls

I have a Datagrid and I attached to it a PreviewKeyDown event.

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Delete)
    {
        DeleteRow();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

My problem is that everytime I edit a cell and try to delete a letter or a digit the DeleteRow method gets called.

Is there any way I can get to know if the cell is being edited to avoid calling the method?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the DataGrid implements IEditableObject so you should be able to get events for when you begin and end editing.

Comment: I'm not sure DataGrid implements IEditableObject, but it definitely has  `BeginningEdit` and `CellEditEnding` events.

Comment: Rick / Nadia I started using the BeginningEdit and CellEditEnding events and created a flag to cpature when the cell is in "edit mode". This provided me of the solution that works for my particular case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After reading Rick's and Nadia's comments I applied the following solution:

```
private void UnitDataGrid_BeginningEdit(object sender, DataGridBeginningEditEventArgs e)
    {
        _isEditing = true;
    }

protected override void OnCellEditEnding(DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
   _isEditing = false;
}
```

By creating these two events and a private attribute (a.k.a a flag) I could write a condition to call a method only when the cell is in edit mode.